# Decimal conversion issue from Oracle to SQL Server via OleDB/Oracle provider

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, oracle11g, oledb

**EDIT: I am now strongly suspecting this behavior is due to a bug in the OleDB.Oracle provider. Upon other testing, I was able to perform Select statements against other CAST column values with negative scale that did *not* cause the 'Decimal byte constructor...' exception. I also note that the provider is returning the *absolute value* of the scale when viewing the schema, eg scale of -2 is returned as 2. Additionally, this same test query does not cause an exception when run through the ODP.NET driver  (rather than the Oracle OLEDB provider). Changing the numeric delimiter as suggested by Lalit (in comments) did not affect the results (but I thank him for his time nonetheless). I continue to research this problem and will advise if more information is realized.**

I have a 64-bit C# application that fetches data from an Oracle database via the Oracle 11g OLEDB provider. When Oracle returns a numeric type defined  or cast with negative scale (such as 'Select Cast(123.1 as Number(3,-1))', the mapped OleDB schema (from `GetSchemaTable`) is reporting that column as a Decimal with a scale of 255. The documentation indicates 255 is intended to represent an N/A or irrelevant value.

When `OleDBDataReader.GetValues()` is later called on the row containing such a column, an ArgumentException is thrown, advising that a 'Decimal byte array constructor...requires four valid decimal bytes," telling me that even though the OleDB Provider thinks its Decimal data, there's no valid Decimal data to read. I'm making an assumption that data is present, but not sure exactly what.

I have tried:

1. Explicitly getting the bytes from the column via calls to `OleDbDataReader.GetBytes` (even a call to size a buffer excepts), but doing so throws "Specified cast is not valid" ArgumentExceptions.
2. Written a chunk of test code to get every possible supported return data type, eg `GetInt16`, `GetInt32`, etc., etc., and each throws the same exception (invalid cast).

Does the Oracle OleDB provider not even return data to the caller when fetching a column defined with a negative scale? Is there some other mechanism to at least get the bytes "across the pond" and manipulate them on the receiving end?

Comment: I can't give you any answer, but as a temporary workaround, maybe you could `CAST(.... AS NUMBER(...,0))`  in your `SELECT`  statement ?

Comment: Unfortunately, @SylvainLeroux, I can't; I have no control over the queries this code executes. Thank you for taking the time to answer - surely appreciate the effort.

Comment: Could you please let us know what privileges do you have on Oracle side? So that we(who can help/assist on Oracle) could specifically suggest you.

Comment: @LalitKumarB Thanks, Lalit...basically, the account I use is very limited - executes the queries involved on the Oracle side of this scenario, and that's about it. If you're looking for anything specific, I would assume that privilege is *not* available.

Comment: Well, since you are into a trouble, and that it would need some privilege to modify either at code level or at session level, but now that you say that you are completely restricted to do any modifications, I am afraid that it is a dauting task to fix your issue.

Comment: Or, at least there should be a way. If you could ask your DBA to look into it.

Comment: @LalitKumarB - My permissions on the *Oracle* side are limited; I obviously have complete discretion over the code and most of the environment from which this executable is run.

Comment: @Lalit Out of curiosity, what would be you strategy to fix that issue if David had enough privileges? Maybe I didn't fully understand the problem, but I thought it was related to the fact that negative scales were not properly handled by the OLEDB provider. Could that be solved without modifying the schema?

Comment: @Sylvain, I had similar thoughts as you mentioned in your first comment. Or, to handle the number fomat by altering the session. But, none of it is possible as OP says. So I have no idea for the fix.

Comment: @LalitKumarB Despite the likely absence of permissions, could you expand on the idea of modifying the session? There may be attributes of the connection I could modify that might lead to an alternative to this situation. Nothing ventured, nothing gained, right? Thanks.

Comment: Search for `nls_numeric_characterset` and alter session to set the parameter accordingly. I might be incorrect, but you might get something for the fix.

Comment: @LalitKumarB So are you suggesting that the Oracle OLEDB driver is, in the case of the negative scale column, errantly returning a string value and, in turn, embedding the decimal separator in the data?

Comment: I don't know anything for sure, since I can't see what's happening at your side. I could just expect something from you based on the suggestions.

Comment: @LalitKumarB On my side, the problem is that when GetValues is called against the OleDbDataReader, an ArgumentException is thrown with the 'Decimal byte constructor...requires four valid decimal bytes'. Internally, the driver is calling SetBits, and when the constructor for the Decimal value is called, the four bytes being passed are failing the validation for a valid decimal value. That suggests to me the driver is putting erroneous values in the reader's buffer for this specific combination of values/parameters. Does that turn on any light bulbs? If its a driver bug, I may be stuck.